# API Ozon | Как получить access_token?

Tags: php, api, postman

По данной доке https://docs.ozon.ru/api/performance/#tag/Token создаю в postman request

POST: https://performance.ozon.ru/api/client/token

Headers:
Host: https://performance.ozon.ru
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

Body:
"client_id":198901,
"client_secret":"b1u5XXDQW3wEqQ7dG...ancMyuhQtMNBI",
"grant_type":"client_credentials"

На что приходит:
400 Bad Request

Что делаю не так?

Comment: формат client_id в доке отличается от вашего, либо вы не верно указали в вопросе, либо передаете не то поле

Comment: попробуйте отправить с теми же данными как и в доке, на выходе должны получить:
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client authentication failed"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня работает в постмане следующим образом (headers и body скопировал из вашего сообщения выше, если что):

**POST**:
https://performance.ozon.ru/api/client/token

**Headers**:

- Content-Type: application/json
- Accept: application/json

**Body** (raw):

{

- "client_id":198901,
- "client_secret":"b1u5XXDQW3wEqQ7dG...ancMyuhQtMNBI",
- "grant_type":"client_credentials"
  }

только client_id для этого запроса должен быть другой. Но с этим, наверное, вы уже разобрались.

**в ответ получите**
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIU...",
"expires_in": 1800,
"token_type": "Bearer"
}